# How to limit the duration of capture video on PhoneGap?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, jquery-mobile, camera

I try to limit the duration of capture video using the CaptureVideoOptions of the PhoneGap API. But the duration parameter is not supported by Android and iOS.

I use this code:

```
navigator.device.capture.captureVideo(onSuccess, onFail , {duration:30});
```

Someone can help me?

Comment: As you already said, it is not supported, so what are you asking for?

Comment: I'm trying to find other solution to limit the duration of video capture. Something like native code or other method of Phonegap API. Do you know any solution? Even other method that I don't said before?

Answer (score 0):

Duration option is supported in phonegap V3.3.0. I have verified it in plugin's CDVCapture.m (plugin's native functionality implementation class).

In case you are still not able to work, You can use following plugin 
"VideoCapturePlus-PhoneGap-Plugin" -https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/VideoCapturePlus-PhoneGap-Plugin

Answer (score -1):

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/cordova_media_capture_capture.md.html

Go to this link,then scroll ..

It is written clearly that it is not supported in Android, Blackberry and IOS .

> **Android Quirks**
>
> The duration parameter is not supported. Recording lengths cannot be
>   limited programmatically. The mode parameter is not supported. The
>   video size and format cannot be altered programmatically; however,
>   these parameters can be changed by the device user. By default, videos
>   are recorded in 3GPP (`video/3gpp`) format.
>
> **BlackBerry WebWorks Quirks**
>
> The duration parameter is not supported. Recording lengths cannot be
>   limited programmatically. The mode parameter is not supported. The
>   video size and format cannot be altered programmatically; however,
>   these parameters can be changed by the device user. By default, videos
>   are recorded in 3GPP (`video/3gpp`) format.
>
> **iOS Quirks**
>
> The limit parameter is not supported. One video is recorded per
>   invocation. The duration parameter is not supported. Recording lengths
>   cannot be limited programmatically. The mode parameter is not
>   supported. The video size and format cannot be altered
>   programmatically. By default, videos are recorded in MOV
>   (`video/quicktime`) format.